# How do you change a scalar function used by a computed column

Tags: sql, calculated-columns

I have a persisted computed column that uses a scalar function to assign the data to it. I noticed that I can't change the function once it's used by the column. In my test environment, I deleted and re-added the column. Once in production, that won't be an option. The table has 24 million rows now and no one will want to drop and re-add the column.

Is there some way to change the function without dropping the column? If the function calls another function, are all functions in the chain not allowed to be changed?

I realize doing this can create inconsistencies in the existing data versus the data being calculated going forward. I don't care about that.

Thanks,
Kevin